# sqlite if no rows returned print 0

Tags: sqlite

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT user_tag, device_type,  ip_address

 FROM
 devices 

 WHERE (user_tag like '|%frt%|'
 OR user_tag like '|%bck%|'
 OR user_tag like '|%ppp%|'
 OR user_tag like '|%smes%|'
 OR user_tag like '|%gm%|')
```

Right now if a record is only returned for the user_tag 'frt' I only receive one row (as you would expect). Is there a way to set a default value for the blank rows, so for example I would receive a value of '0' or something similar for the rows that don't return any real data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is a 'rough draft'. Since I work with all types of SQL, I have trouble with SQLite-specific syntax sometimes, and I don't have any way to test this query right now, so it may need some syntax modification.

But it gets the idea cross... **Using your list of hard-coded values, make it a subquery and do a left join on it instead of a where.**

user_tag_exists should be 0 when there aren't any user tags for the type given.

```
Select CASE WHEN d.user_tag is null THEN '0' ELSE '1' END AS user_tag_exists,
       tagTypes.tagType,
       d.user_tag, d.device_type, d.ip_address
From
(
    Select '%frt%' as tagType
    UNION
    Select '%bck%' as tagType
    UNION
    Select '%ppp%' as tagType
    UNION
    Select '%smes%' as tagType
    UNION
    Select '%gm%' as tagType
) as tagTypes
left join
    devices d
        on d.device_type like tagTypes.tagType
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I made a SQL Fiddle of it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6b52/1 and it doesn't seem to be running correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Ben, that's a really neat tool! I'll definitely be using it in the future. I'm updating the answer with the changes.. The way you set up the data, you gave device_type the ppp..bck.. etc. But in your example, your where was on user_tag.

Comment: ah, I see that now. user_tag is the correct choice, i just mixed them up

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want:

1. A value of '0' in a column instead of null
2. A row with '0's if
   no user_tag exists that are like a value.

If you are looking for 1), you can use a CASE statement.

```
 SELECT 
        user_tag, 
        CASE WHEN device_type is not null THEN device_type ELSE '0' END as device_type, 
        ip_address

 FROM
 devices 

 WHERE (user_tag like '|%frt%|'
 OR user_tag like '|%bck%|'
 OR user_tag like '|%ppp%|'
 OR user_tag like '|%smes%|'
 OR user_tag like '|%gm%|')
```

This would give you a **device_type** of '0' even if **device_type** was null.

Comment: Thanks. I received this error ERROR [HY000] near ",": syntax error (1)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a way right now to check my SQLite syntax. I edited the query, I forgot to add an **end** statement. I added an **as** statement as well.

Comment: Looking more at this, I am actually looking for option # 2 'A row with '0's if no user_tag exists that are like a value."

Comment: Sorry, the query given is only for columns with nulls, not like statements that are missing. While you could write a query to do what you want, it might be easier to handle this in code and not SQLite. The only way I can think of doing this would be very complex.

Comment: Can you let me know basically what you are thinking query-wise so I can do some research on my own?

Comment: Sure! Let me put it in another answer, it'll be a little long.

Comment: I have a follow up to yesterday's discussion. Is there another way to reach you or is this forum the best way? Thanks