# How to get data for a month using sqlite ? If there is no data for a specific date then i want zero on place of that

Tags: android, ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I already know that **How can I get data for a month ?** using this query -

```
SELECT SLIDER_VALUE FROM TBL_ACTIVITY_TRACKS WHERE STRFTIME('%m', TRACK_DATE_TIME, 'localtime') = STRFTIME('%m', 'now', 'localtime');

Here TRACK_DATE_TIME is in yyyy-mm-dd date format.
```

But i want that if there is no data for a particular date then i want zero or a specific identifier on place of that.

I also know that I can do this by creating a TBL_DATES. which have all dates and then left join it with my table but I don't want to create a new table.

Can I do this ?

Comment: please first show your table fields here

Comment: I think there is no need of that let there is only three fields
ID, SLIDER_VALUE and TRACK_DATE_TIME
as I mentioned in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the individual date values from *somewhere*.
If you do not want to create a temporary table, you can embed the values into a subquery directly in your statement:

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(Slider_Value, 'none')
FROM (SELECT '2013-10-01' AS Date
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '2013-10-02'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '2013-10-03'
      UNION ALL
      ...
      SELECT '2013-10-31'
     ) AS ThisMonth
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Activity_Tracks ON ThisMonth.Date = date(Track_Date_Time)
```

If you do not want to enumerate the days in the code that generates the SQL statement, you can also do this in SQL itself, with enough contortions:

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(Slider_Value, 'none')
FROM (SELECT date('now', 'start of month') AS Date
      UNION ALL
      SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+1 days')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+2 days')
      UNION ALL
      ...
      UNION ALL
      SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+27 days')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+28 days') WHERE strftime('%m', 'now', 'start of month', '+28 days') = strftime('%m', 'now')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+29 days') WHERE strftime('%m', 'now', 'start of month', '+29 days') = strftime('%m', 'now')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+30 days') WHERE strftime('%m', 'now', 'start of month', '+30 days') = strftime('%m', 'now')
     ) AS ThisMonth
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Activity_Tracks ON ThisMonth.Date = date(Track_Date_Time)
```

(The last three WHERE clauses omit days that are no longer in the current month, for months with less than 31 days.)

Comment: First of all thanks for answering.
How can i add dates for different-2 months manually. Let my current month have 30 days and next current month have 31 days then how i manually change the dates and month in query.

Is there not an other way?

Comment: This is not easily done in SQL; you should do this in your Java/ObjC code.

Comment: Is there not an other way? Instead on manually doing all this the TBL_Dates is the better solution that I already used in a project of mine. I am always looking for a better solution.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "better"?

Comment: I don't have to do this type of manual work or don't have to create a extra table only for this purpose and update the dates of it after the time. As i added dates for a year in my previous app so I have to update it after a year.
I appreciate your help so I have given +1 to your answer but if it is done by more appropriate way if any one knows any special sqlite function or done it in a better way as of us.

Comment: You would not use a fixed query but generate the list of dates for the current month whenever you use it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understood your last comment

Comment: You could use the Java date functions to generate the list of dates for the current month.

Comment: You updated the answer, I didn't seen the next part that's really something improved. Thanks for that and Sorry I am using Objective-C in iOS Application Development there is no tag for java in my question.

Comment: You are using Objective-C in Android? Anyway, replace "Java" with "iOS".

Comment: You have to add 'localtime' to the date function because the date('now') returns the GMT date not the local date.
Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to **pass the database query return values in an ArrayList** & then you **get the *size()* of the ArrayList**. If it is *greater than zero you can do your operation on it*, else *if there is no data you can **pass zero** or do the respective operation*.

Comment: I am not considering the case if there is no data returned by the query, I already know that. I want zero if there is no data for a particular date. Please read the question properly.

Comment: You cannot do it by any SQLQuery. You can do one thing is that you can get the count of the SQL cursor to check if it has data or not and return values accordingly.

Comment: Buddy I am not asking that a query something returning or not. I am asking if i don't have values for a particular date and have for other dates then i want zero for other dates in that case your array list or cursor count always greater than zero.

Comment: your question states that if there is no data then you want zero. The data for the particular date can only be fetched running an SQL Query. So, only the query can return either the data for the date or a zero. Please update your question if you have not got the answer as per your need, so that it can be clear what you actually want.

Comment: Please re-read my question

"How to get data for a month using sqlite ? If there is no data for a specific date then i want zero on place of that."

and description also. You didn't read it properly till now.

Comment: ok try this link it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509320/sqlite-if-no-rows-returned-print-0

Comment: Thanks its same as CL answered above.