# How to get dates of current month or as specified month using sqlite query?

Tags: android, ios, sql, sqlite

In my application I want to use all dates of the current month that I have to use in my other query to join.

If I can get dates for specified month means by passing the month number than also I don't have any problem.

I need to do it using query using sqlite database.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please show your database and tables that you said first.

Comment: @MajidDaeiNejad: We don't need database or tables for that we can do it by the inbuilt functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative condensed solution:

```
SELECT DATE(JULIANDAY('NOW', 'START OF MONTH')+d1*9+d2*3+d3) AS Days FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
) JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS d2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2
) JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS d3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2
) WHERE STRFTIME('%m', Days)=STRFTIME('%m', 'NOW') ORDER BY Days;
```

Note this solution requires more computation then @CL one.

Answer (score 2):

To quote [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19487760/11654):

```
SELECT date('now', 'start of month') AS Date
UNION ALL
SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+1 days')
UNION ALL
SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+2 days')
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+27 days')
UNION ALL
SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+28 days') WHERE strftime('%m', 'now', 'start of month', '+28 days') = strftime('%m', 'now')
UNION ALL
SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+29 days') WHERE strftime('%m', 'now', 'start of month', '+29 days') = strftime('%m', 'now')
UNION ALL
SELECT date('now', 'start of month', '+30 days') WHERE strftime('%m', 'now', 'start of month', '+30 days') = strftime('%m', 'now')
```

Comment: Hi CL can I get dates for specified month ? What changes I have to made for it.

Comment: Replace `'now', 'start of month'` with the date of the start of that month, e.g., `'2013-10-01'`.

Comment: I think, I have to create function for that to pass the date of the start of the month. Currently I have created a view as of your query.